# Why BDD focuses on validation while TDD focuses on verification

Tags: validation, tdd, bdd, verification

I've read [TDD and BDD Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395469/tdd-and-bdd-differences) and [What are the primary differences between TDD and BDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-tdd-and-bdd).

Here was [(part of) an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396952/2605041):

> BDD is just TDD with different words. If you do TDD right, you are doing BDD. The difference is that – provided you believe at least in the weak form of the Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis – the different words make it easier to do it right.

But I still haven't been able to understand why BDD focuses on validation while TDD focuses on verification.

The question about BDD vs. TDD (and validation and verification) came up in a quiz problem:

> What is the main difference between BDD and TDD?
>
> 1. BDD focuses on validation while TDD focuses on verification
> 2. BDD focuses on verification while TDD focuses on validation
> 3. BDD is better than TDD at testing methods independently
> 4. BDD generally uses mocks and stubs more than TDD

The answer to the question was **(1)**. Would someone elaborate on why "BDD focuses on validation while TDD focuses on verification"?

Comment: My question is clear: Why does "BDD focus on validation while TDD focuses on verification"?

Comment: Would really have liked an answer to this